# Determine whether $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous or discontinuous from the right or left at $x_0=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine whether $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous or discontinuous from the right or left at $x_0=0$

Left?
$f(0^-)$ =>  not defined , then $f(0^-) \neq f(0)$
 , it shows that $f(x)$ is discontinuous from the left at $x_0=0$

Right?
$f(0^+) = 0 = f(0)$, it shows that $f(x)$ is continuous from the right at $x_0=0$

Is this sufficient? Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't say it is discontinuous from the left, since there is no left of $0$ for this function. It is continuous from the right, by your argument

Comment: You are right. Left hand limit doesn't exist.  It is not undefined. That is called one sided limit! The function itself $\sqrt x$ is continuous at $x=0$.. That is called  end point continuity!

Comment: Some introductory calculus textbooks will say $\sqrt{x}$ is discontinuous at 0. The rationale goes like: to be continuous at a point, the limits on either side must be equal; since the function is undefined on one side, the limit does not exist on that side; since one limit does not exist, they cannot be equal; so the function is discontinuous. I believe the point is to avoid introducing more complicated ideas about domain. I can give an explicit example when I get to my office.

Comment: So, it really depends on your definition of continuity. You'll have to give us that before we can answer you properly.